# What is "selection modeling"?

Tags: terminology, causality

Gelman & Zelizer ([2014](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/rd_china_5.pdf)) write:

> five other methods used for causal inference in observational studies: simple regression, matching, selection modeling, difference in differences, and instrumental variables

What is "selection modeling"?

Answer (score 2):

It probably refers to something like what is done in [Tobit/Heckmann-type Models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobit_model). This would make sense, because they "model" the "selection". Also, Gelman & Zelizer's next sentence would make sense then

> selection  modeling  is  sensitive  to  untestable  distributional  assumptions

But admittedly, "selection modelling" is not a common term